# Цепные методы в JS

Tags: javascript

Поставлена задача: написать калькулятор, который включает в себя различные операции (+ - * / ^) с поддержкой цепных методов. Так же должен учитываться приоритет операторов. Пример:

```
const calculator = new SmartCalculator(2);

  const value = calculator
    .add(2)
    .multiply(2);

  console.log(value); // 6
```

Т.е. нужно возвращать не только ответ, но и this, чтобы учитывать последовательность операторов. Как можно вернуть ответ, чтобы не потерять this?

Comment: Основная идея "цепных методов" в том, что необходимо, чтобы метод возвращал тот же объект, на котором вызван этот метод. То есть метод add должен возвращать не число (или строку, или вообще что угодно), а объект `calculator`. Тогда при последующем вызове `multiply` выполнится метод `multiply` объекта `calculator`.

Answer (score 1):

Как я уже писал в комментарии к вопросу:

> Основная идея "цепных методов" в том, что необходимо, чтобы метод
>   возвращал тот же объект, на котором вызван этот метод. То есть метод
>   add должен возвращать не число (или строку, или вообще что угодно), а
>   объект calculator. Тогда при последующем вызове multiply выполнится
>   метод multiply объекта calculator.

```
class SmartCalculator {
    constructor(initialValue) {
        this.value = initialValue;
    }

    add(operand) {
        this.value += operand;
        return this;
    }

    multiply(operand) {
        this.value *= operand;
        return this;
    }
}

const calculator = new SmartCalculator(2);

  const value = calculator
    .add(2)
    .multiply(2);

  console.log(value); // 6
```

Однако здесь возникает неоднозначная ситуация. `console.log()` в последней строчке выводит не число `6`, а объект, у которого поле `value` содержит значение `6`.

Если не принципиально, то можно так и вывести:

```
console.log(value.value);
```

Но если принципиально, то я пока вижу одно решение: добавить "завершающий метод", вызов которого будет возвращать результат, а не объект:

```
class SmartCalculator {
    constructor(initialValue) {
        this.value = initialValue;
    }

    add(operand) {
        this.value += operand;
        return this;
    }

    multiply(operand) {
        this.value *= operand;
        return this;
    }

    get result() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

const calculator = new SmartCalculator(2);

  const value = calculator
    .add(2)
    .multiply(2)
    .result;

  console.log(value); // 6
```

Кстати, ответ здесь будет не 6, а 8, поскольку методы вызываются по-порядку.

---

Набросал по-быстрому вариант с соблюдением приоритета:

```
class SmartCalculator {
    constructor(initialValue) {
        this.value = initialValue.toString();
        this.expression = "";
        this.valueUsed = false;
    }

    add(operand) {
        this.expression += `${this.useExpOrValue(operand)} + ${operand}`;
        return this;
    }

    multiply(operand) {
        this.expression += `${this.useExpOrValue(operand)} * ${operand}`;
        return this;
    }

    useExpOrValue(operand) {
        let res = !this.valueUsed ? this.value : "";
        this.valueUsed = true;
        return res;
    }

    get result() {
        console.log(this.expression);
        return eval(this.expression);
    }
}

const calculator = new SmartCalculator(2);

  const value = calculator
    .add(2)
    .multiply(2)
    .result;

  console.log(value); // 6
```

Однако использовать его я крайне не рекомендую по понятным причинам: во-первых - костыль, во-вторых - `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
 const value = calculator
    .add(2)
    .multiply(2)
    .calculate();
```

Всё до `calculate` это сборка выражения с учётом порядка операторов, а сам расчёт делается в `calculate();`

Comment: Тоже думал об этом, но есть тесты, в которых примерно такой код: `const calculator = new SmartCalculator(2);

    const value = calculator
      .add(2)
      .multiply(2);

    assert.equal(value, 6);`

Comment: @Max Тут какая-то несостыковка, если у вас возвращается число в результате действий калькулятора, то вы даже не выполните последовательность действий так как после действия уже не объект калькулятора возвращается а число, поэтому вывод что нужно возвращать объект калькулятора, но отсюда следует что конструкция в вашем коде просто не сработает.

Comment: @Max Да вы и сами это уже поняли.

Comment: Конечно в value можно возвращать сложный объект в котором есть и калькулятор и значение, но тогда опять же что бы value вытащить потребуется отдельная операция, и код теста снова не сработает.

Comment: Я думаю, вам стоит глянуть в сторону метода `valueOf`, если вы и правда хотите нечто подобное, но вариант с `calculate()` выглядит лучше ИМХО.

Comment: Спасибо за советы, все решилось переопределением toString().

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать как-то в таком духе (возведение в степень делать поленился):

```js
class SmartCalculator {
  constructor(initValue) {
    this.init = initValue;
    this.operations = [];
  }
  get result() {
    let rpn = [this.init]; // reverse polish notation
    let ops = [];

    this.operations.forEach(op => { // сортировочная станция
      while (ops.length && (ops[ops.length - 1]).priority < op.priority) {
        rpn.push(ops.pop().op);
      }
      ops.push(op);
      rpn.push(op.val);
    });
    while (ops.length) {
      rpn.push(ops.pop().op)
    }
    let res = [];
    rpn.forEach(token => {
      if (typeof token === 'function') {
        res.push(token(res.pop(), res.pop()));
      } else {
        res.push(token);
      }
    });
    return res.pop();
  }
  add(val) {
    this.operations.push({
      op: (a, b) => a + b,
      priority: 2,
      val: val
    });
    return this;
  }
  substract(val) {
    this.operations.push({
      op: (a, b) => b - a,
      priority: 2,
      val: val
    })
    return this;
  }
  multiply(val) {
    this.operations.push({
      op: (a, b) => a * b,
      priority: 1,
      val: val
    })
    return this;
  }
  divide(val) {
    this.operations.push({
      op: (a, b) => b / a,
      priority: 1,
      val: val
    })
    return this;
  }
  valueOf() {
    return this.result;
  }
}

const value = new SmartCalculator(2)
  .add(2)
  .multiply(2);

console.log(value == 6);
console.log(+value);
```